# WooCommerce - Show parent taxonomy with link from child taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce and custom templates for categories. I am trying to output the parent category of the current taxonomy a customer is viewing to act as a "back" button or a "jump up a category" link.

The output needs to create a shortcode so that this can be placed within a custom template builder. Or I was add to XYZ Snippets which will create a  shortcode for a function.

I attempted a snippet but nothing outputs on the frontend.

**Please help!**

Example Category Tree (With parent highlighted):

```
    
    Furniture
    Furniture Chairs (Would show "Furniture")Armchair (Would show "Chairs")Wooden Armchairs (Would show "Armchair")
```

```
function product_category_parent_shortcode() {
$cat = get_queried_object();

$cats = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => $cat->taxonomy,
    'child_of' => $cat->parent,
] );

if ( ! empty( $cats ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
        $url = esc_url( get_category_link( $cat ) );
        // change the 'before' and/or 'after' or whatever necessary
        echo "<li>before <a href='$url'>$cat->name</a> after</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
}
add_shortcode('product_category_parent', 'product_category_parent_shortcode');
```

I also have tried the following snippet, but results are not consistent. The category link it outputs sometimes works but sometimes does not which leads me to think the code is searching in the wrong place. The code is designed to search a single product terms, and not a category as needed.

```
// Get parent product categories on single product pages
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'include_children' => false ) );

// Get the first main product category (not a child one)
$term = reset($terms);
$term_link =  get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' ); // The link
echo '<h2 class="link"><a href="'.$term_link.'">Return</a></h2>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to display a breadcrumb style tax parent list, you could just use [get_term_parents_list](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_parents_list/)

e.i.

```
add_shortcode('cat-list-breadcrumb', function() {
    if ( !is_tax() && !is_category() && !is_tag() )
        return 'Dont call me here peasant!';

    $obj = get_queried_object();
    $options = [
        'separator' => ' / ',
        'inclusive' => false
    ];
    return get_term_parents_list( $obj->term_id, $obj->taxonomy , $options ). ' '. $obj->name;
});
```

if you need to build your own html format, then use [get_ancestors](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/)

```
add_shortcode('cat-list', function() {
    
    if ( !is_tax() && !is_category() && !is_tag() )
        return;
        
    $obj = get_queried_object();
    
    $output = '<ul>';
    
    $parents = get_ancestors( $obj->term_id,  $obj->taxonomy );
   
    foreach ( array_reverse( $parents ) as $termId ) {
        $parent = get_term( $termId, $obj->taxonomy );
        $out .= '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $parent->term_id, $obj->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . $parent->name . '</a></li>';

    } 

    $out .= '<li>'.$obj->name . '</li>';
    return $out.'</ul>';
});
```

if you want to display only the 1st level parent but not the 2nd to top level then just use [get_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) on `get_queried_object` `parent` value

e.i.

```
add_shortcode('cat-parent', function() {
    
    if ( !is_tax() && !is_category() && !is_tag() )
        return;
        
    $obj = get_queried_object();
    
    if ( !$obj->parent )
        return;
        
    $parent = get_term( $obj->parent, $obj->taxonomy );
    
    return '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $parent->term_id, $obj->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . $parent->name . '</a>';

});
```

Comment: Great answer. Love all the options but option 3 (the last) was exactly what I needed.